# Sync/Save list data from root site to subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, multilingual

Is it possible to save newly created item from list one from the root site to the same list in the other sub site.

Currently we are implementing country specific site and we have the global site where the global news and announcement will be published then it will also be available to the country sites

```
Global Site
 ----> News List
     News 1

/en-US
 ----> News List
     News 1 from root site
     News en-US
/en-PH
 ---> News List
    News PH
    News 1 from root site
```

Need your help and suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint workflow cannot create items in the list in another site.

As a workaround for SharePoint Online, deploy the **Remote Event Receiver** to monitor the events in the list. The code/operations in an event receiver can be triggered when an item is created/modified/deleted, then copy item to another list in another site.

Demo: [Create a remote event receiver in SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-an-add-in-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins)